# How do I remove applications that android automatically downloads, and stop it downloading apps that I don't want automatically?

Tags: google-apps, default-applications, android-device-manager

I have an android phone, and every now and again, when I connect to WiFi, I notice it starts automatically downloading updates.

However, it also seems to download/ update a number of default apps, which I never use.

I now find myself running out of space, and don't want to delete the apps I do use (banking, traveling, etc), and don't want to delete photos, videos etc, until I am able to back them up to my computer...

I have tried removing a number of these apps (Flipboard, Google Play Books,  Music, etc, Google +), but they all still seem to be there. When I uninstall them/ set back to factory, they just seem to automatically update again when I next connect to WiFi.

I don't anticipate ever having a need for these apps, so how can I permanently remove them, and remove them from the automatic updates, to free up space for messages, photos, etc?

Answer (score 1):

- In general, to prevent auto updates - - Disable auto updates. Google Play Store → Settings → General → Do not auto update
- The apps you mentioned seem to be *system apps*, those that came with the device (not user installed). You can remove  those only if your device is rooted. **But** this is not going to help you save space as they occupy space on the `/system` partition, which is not available to you.
- However, you can reclaim some space by removing the updates of these apps.  Thanks to Izzy, who pointed in comments (now deleted)

> If the apps are not to be used anyway, better approach is going to Settings › Apps and to disable them altogether – including force-stop and delete cache + data. That way: no more auto-updates for them, cleaner app-drawer, plus space saved (date + cache being removed). And don't forget that those updates indeed use up space outside `/system` (updates go to `/data`, regardless of system app or not)

- **If you need more space** You haven't mentioned your device /Android version and whether it supports ext.SD card. If you are on Android version 6 and above you can convert your ext.SD to [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage) or root your device and move apps to ext. SD. If these options are not possible, you are out of luck, barring using a cloud based service to back up

Comment: What about this answer is new, a question that can also be placed against the original query? Where is the [duplicate] indicator?

Comment: @wbogaczb I don't follow you. Are you saying that this a dupe? Could be but I couldn't find it. If you find it please flag. To clarify, I had deleted my original answer after Izzy clarified an important aspect (see edit history) and requested him to answer but he suggested that I amend the answer, which I did

Comment: [This Query](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=automatic%20update) yielded 7 relevant questions focused on this just within 2 pgs of 850+ posts. Here are the numbers for reference of my opinioned duplicate questions, since full links would exceed comment length: 200384, 2051, 68785, 190791, 12058, 162909, 196134, and undoubtedly more on the further unread pages of search results.

Comment: @wbogaczb :Thanks for pointing out. May I request you to flag what you feel is the closest dupe?  I certainly didn't dig deep. I will happily take down my answer if dupe

Comment: Clearly my earlier search was cursory and I agree that dupes should be closed @wbogaczb